# equivalence in the definition between 2 norms

Tags: matrices, definition, normed-spaces

This is a practice question for an exam, which im not able to figure out.

Show that these two definitions of norms are equivalent:
$||A||_2=\max_{||v||_2=1}||Av||_2$ and $||A||_2=\max_{x,y} \frac{x^tAy}{||x||_2||y||_2}$.

Can someone help me in showing their equivalence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second formulation, fix $x$ and find the $y$ that maximizes the expression.